# google cloud vm ssh network error: connection timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a GCP Linux VM from my local Windows 10 machine using google cloud SDK.

I have two wifi networks at home. When I run the command `gcloud compute ssh VM_name`, I can connect to the VM through only one of the networks. On the other network, I receive the following error from puTTy:

> puTTy FATAL ERROR: Network error. Connection timed out.

Both networks are from the same internet service provider. Why is it not connecting through one of them? Which settings should I look into?